# IntelliJ: Could not target platform: 'Java SE 12' using tool chain: 'JDK 11 (11)'

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

First of all, I read similar questions and none of them could help me solve it. I use Gradle for building the project. Although I'm using Java 12 (Java 12 is written in the project structure, module settings and run configs) and I tried invalidating the caches and restart. I still keep getting the error I mentioned in the title when I start running my program. Does anyone have any idea on the possible solution?

Comment: Show us your build.gradle. Also show us the result of running "java -version"

Answer (score 29):

Your can select the correct JDK under:

Intellij IDEA -> Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> Gradle JVM

[image]

Comment: Does work when you build with Intellij, but doesn't work when you build in the Intellij console :)

Comment: Jan S. Thank you! That was the issue for IntelliJ indeed! 
@Blank: As for the console of IntelliJ, you'll have to change your JAVA_HOME variable to point to JAVA SE 12 and then put it in the PATH too; this procedure is different though amongst operating systems.

Comment: @panagiotis I know, I wanted to tell exactly that. I should have added that you need to change the JAVA_HOME variable ^^ mea culpa.

Answer (score 0):

FYI I ran into this problem recently with a project I had previously opened, which then got upgraded to Java 11. Every conceivable place in the IDE & project configs was set to Java 11, but I still got the error.

Ultimately, the solution was to remove the .idea directory and reconstruct the project from the build.gradle file. Apparently some JDK configuration setting was cached somewhere that isn't visible in the UI anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using IntelliJ Idea. I tried setting SDK from 'Project Structure' as well as setting gradle JVM, but it did not work until I set JAVA_HOME in intellij terminal.

```
set JAVA_HOME="C:/Program Files/Java/java12"
```

Then, I ran gradle build. And, it worked.